# Will search engines be able to find meta tag information echoed from a PHP script?

Tags: php, html, metadata, search-engine

I'm thinking of doing something along the lines of:

```
<?php
  $title = "Title of current page";
  include("head.php");
?>

<h1>The stuff that goes inside the BODY tag</h1>

<?php
  include("foot.php");
?>
```

The Keywords and Description Meta tags will be echoed from within the head.php script. If I do that will search engines be able to read the Keywords and Description? And if it does, how badly would it effect search engine rank?

Comment: It won't make a jot of different to mister Googles.

Comment: On a side note, as far as I have been led to understand, meta data is fast becoming *unimportant*. By this I mean, the indexing value of relevant keywords peppered throughout content in a semantically well structured document greatly exceeds that of a block of meta data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Search engines have no knowledge about your server-side includes.  If you open your page in a browser, and select "View Source", you will see exactly what search engines see.  That is what you want to consider, not your PHP source code.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I was aware that search engines can't see server-side scripts, but that was what got me curious in the first place. I just didn't know that search engines run the code to read the resulting HTML as opposed to the HTML in the file.

Comment: @Hexel: The web server is responsible for running the script.  When you connect to `example.com/page.php`, the server responds by finding `page.php`, executing the php, and sending back the final `HTML` output.  It doesn't matter if a client, user, command-line script, robot, etc. makes the request.  If there ever was a way to get direct access to the source `HTML` that would be a major security hole.

Answer (score 1):

isn't that all just server side scripting?  What does the final presented file look like?  Won't that be the only thing search engines are capable of considering?

Comment: Yes.. Yes.. Yes..  Is this an answer or another question :)